# SAPUI5: Same view with different titles and data.How to navigate to and from such a view.

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have created a view which based on a condition displays different data with a different title. Say View1. From View1, if I navigate to another view View2. How to navigate back to View1 with the required data and correct title.

Comment: What "title" do you mean? The HTML document title or the title of  `sap.m.Page`? How are the views structured? What kind of [floorplan](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/floorplan-overview/#overview-of-floorplans) do you use? Please, show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

Defining router:

```
   new Router(
    // Routes
    [
        {
            // no view creation related properties are in the route
            name: "appRouter",
            //no hash
            pattern: "samplePattern", 
            // you can find this target in the targetConfig
            target: "view1"
        }
    ],
    // Default values shared by routes and Targets
    {
        viewNamespace: "your.app.namespace",
        viewType: "XML"
    },
    null,
    // Target config
    {
         //same name as in the route called 'startRoute'
         view1: {
             // All properties for creating and placing a view 
             //go here or in the config
             viewName: "view1",
             controlId: "app",
             controlAggregation: "pages"
         }
    })
```

If you already have router:

```
var oRouter = sap.ui.core.routing.Router.getRouter("appRouter");

//can also use directly oRouter.navTo if you're extending 
//scaffloding OR base controllers of SAP UI5.
oRouter.navTo("samplePattern",oContext,false);
```

[Read more here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Router)